# Checkout SVN on the console if the server uses a different SSH port

Tags: svn, ssh, port

On my server I use another SSH port than 22.

In my Smartgit GUI I can still access the svn repository by adding the port in the repo url, before I usedstandard port 22:

```
svn+ssh://example.org/var/svn-repos/project/trunk
```

Now I use for port 1234:

```
svn+ssh://example.org:1234/var/svn-repos/project/trunk
```

this works in Smartgit, but it doesn't if I try to use it on the console:

```
ssh example.org -p 1234
cd /tmp/
svn co svn+ssh://example.org:1234/var/svn-repos/project/trunk
```

I get

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname example.org:1234: Name or service not known
svn: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

I looked inside `/etc/subversion/config` But it seems to me, I would do more damage then good, if I change anything there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think a custom tunnel specified in ~/.subversion/config is your best bet.

See [how-to-configure-svn-ssh-with-ssh-on-non-standard-port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27143/how-to-configure-svn-ssh-with-ssh-on-non-standard-port)